# Why doesn't the "include" work in the example code?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, include

The direction structure the following

- Source folder

  - Engine

    - Classes

      - CalendarClass.php
    - Database

      - Other
      - DBLink.php
  - Fonts
  - Imgages
  - JS
  - Pages

    - Calendar.php
  - Style

When I trying to include the DBLink.php class to the CalendarClass.php, I get the following error messages:

*Warning: include(../Database/DBLink.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\apache\htdocs\Engine\Classes\CalendarClass.php on line 3*

*Warning: include(): Failed opening '../Database/DBLink.php' for inclusion (include_path='D:\apache\php\PEAR') in D:\apache\htdocs\Engine\Classes\CalendarClass.php on line 3*

*Fatal error: Class 'DBLink' not found in D:\apache\htdocs\Engine\Classes\CalendarClass.php on line 10*

The content of the CalendarClass.php:

```
<?php

include "../Database/DBLink.php";

class CalendarClass{

    private $link;

     function __construct() {
        $this->link = new DBLink();
    }

    function UpdateCalendar(){
        $this->link->ClearCalendar();
    }

}

?>
```

What is the right way to include the DbLink.php to the CalendarClass.php ?

Comment: The error is talking in plain English! No such file or directory!

Comment: Make sure rights are setup properly... That's my normal first step the when I can verify that the file is at the location it said it is not

Comment: The include __DIR__ . "/../Database/DBLink.php" is work! Thanks a lot KhorneHoly! You saved a lot of time for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
__DIR__ . "/../Database/DBLink.php";
```

PHP is looking for this file, but starts at a different `root path`.

You need to provide a full path so that PHP will look up the correct path.

`__DIR__` provides the path to the directoy the file lies in.

An easier way would be to use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.autoload.php)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Change the include to include `__DIR__ . "/../Database/DBLink.php"`